# Rails: How to set expiration time for session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I am not able to set expiration time for session cookie. below is my code.

```
session[:mobile_number] = { value: "XJ-122", expires: 1.hour.from_now }
```

However i am able to do it with plain cookie   `cookies[:login] = { :value => "XJ-122", :expires => 1.hour.from_now }` so whats the problem with session cookie ?? why it is not expiring after 1 hour??

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Rails has no way to dynamically set the expire time of the session cookie.

You can set expire time in the `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
Some::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  key: "some_session_id",
  domain: ".awesome.com",
  expire_after: 24.hours,
}
```

Comment: or we can do it like this also... cookies.signed[:mobile_number] =  { value: "XJ-122", expires: 1.minutes.from_now}.  This will encrypt cookie same as session[:mobile_number] and allow us to set expire time. am i right??